# Issues Templates for JIRA Core Workflows

Tags: task, workflow, jira, jira-plugin, issue-tracking

Not sure if I have the correct community however I thought this would be a great place to start.

Our company recently purchased "JIRA Core" and we would like to add preset issues to a workflow, as all our projects have default tasks. I have no idea how to do this or where I should start.

I would love some guidance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Are you asking for advice on using the "Issue Templates for JIRA" plugin?

Comment: Our company provides web services to clients. The majority of these services is web development. Each project will go through its usual project phases from Sales > Onboarding > Kickoff > Design > Development > Testing > Launch.
With each phase of the project life cycle, there are common tasks (or issues). What I am seeking is to apply phase a workflow with preset tasks (or issues) rather than creating them every single time a new project is created within JIRA Core.
How do I create preset tasks to a specific workflow?
Regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The (arguably) simplest approach is to create one project with all of the settings you need (statuses, workflows & schemes, issues & schemes, security & schemes, etc.)
For each project thereafter that follows the same paradigm, in the `create project` popup, select `Create with shared configuration` and choose the project that was previously set up.

[image: Shared config]

Any updates to the workflows, issues, etc. will then apply to all projects created this way (providing you don't change the schema-to-project mapping).

Over time, you'll have projects that follow different paradigms (for instance, I set up three "configurations" across 15 projects for a client - one for business departments, one for software development and one for legal / administrative).